# Regex Match 1 Digit From Time Format And Replace With 2 Digits

Tags: regex

I have text like this

```
Thu 8 Apr,4:45,5:54,11:55,3:12,5:55,7:00
```

I want to change 1 digit hour to 2 digits, so i can get

```
04:45,05:54,11:55,03:12,05:55,07:00
```

I tried regex with the folowing

```
(\d{1}:\d+,)|(?:\d{2}:\d+,)|(\d:\d+)
```

Replace match list with

```
0$&
```

And Get List:

```
04:45,05:54,011:55,03:12,05:55,07:00
```

As you can see 11:55 is also added 0, how to fix that in order that 2 digits is not added by 0?
Thank You!

Comment: Match `/\b\d:/` and replace with `0$&`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Converting my comment to answer so that solution is easy to find for future visitors.

In Javascript, you can match using this regex:

```
\b\d:
```

and replace with:

```
0$&
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Z0GFTw/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `\b`: Match word boundary
- `\d`: Match a single digit
- `:`: Match a colon
- `0$&`: is the [replacement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/lastMatch) that puts `0` before every matched substring

**Code:**

```js
const s = `Thu 8 Apr,4:45,5:54,11:55,3:12,5:55,7:00`

var r = s.replace(/\b\d:/g, '0$&')

console.log( r )

//=> Thu 8 Apr,04:45,05:54,11:55,03:12,05:55,07:00
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
\b([0-9]:)
```

Replace with `0$1`. See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/QpktpY/4). Result: `Thu 8 Apr,04:45,05:54,11:55,03:12,05:55,07:00`.

**EXPLANATION**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w) and
                           something that is not a word char
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [0-9]                    any character of: '0' to '9'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    :                        colon
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
```